# density of fractal measures

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, fractals, hausdorff-dimension

Let $s\in (0, 1)$ be a real number. Let $E\subset [0, 1]$ be a Borel set whose Hausdorff dimension is given by $s$. Assume that $\mathcal{H}^s(E)=+\infty$, that is, the $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure of $E$ is $+\infty$.

We define lower density 
$$
\underline{D}^s(E, x):=\underline{\lim}_{r\to 0} \frac{\mathcal{H}^s(E\cap (x-r, x+r))}{(2r)^s}
$$
Similarly we define upper density 
$$
\overline{D}^s(E, x):=\overline{\lim}_{r\to 0} \frac{\mathcal{H}^s(E\cap (x-r, x+r))}{(2r)^s}
$$
Define a set 
$$
\widetilde{E}:=\{x\in [0, 1]: \overline{D}^s(E, x)>0\}.
$$
My question is, do we have 
$$
\mathcal{H}^{s+\epsilon}(\widetilde{E})=0,
$$
for every $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: You can have $H^s(E\cap I)=+\infty$ for every open interval $I$. What are you going to do then?

Comment: @fedja I see. I saw a density theorem in a book of Falconer for $0<\mathcal{H}^s(E)<\infty$. However I did not find any density theorem for the case of infinity. Could you give me a reference, or there is a simple construction? Thanks!

Comment: You can find an $s$-dimensional set $E_0$ of infinite $H^s$ measure on $[0,1]$, cannot you? Now just take $E=\cup_{a,b\in \mathbb Q, a<b}T_{a,b}E_0$ where $T_{a,b}$ is a linear map of $[0,1]$ onto $[a,b]$.